# Unity3d: Collider with an object and update its transform, then loses all rigidbody attributes and falls through objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

```
 private void Start()
{
    connected = false;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.tag == "Player")
    {
        dronePlayer = collision;

        offset = dronePlayer.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position;

        connected = true;
    }   
}

private void Update()
{
    if (connected)
    {
        transform.position = dronePlayer.transform.position - offset;
    }
}
```

Simply, all I want to do it pick up an object from another object after a collision and then move around. So the script just changes the transform of the object I hit with a transform.

The problem here is that all works ok except when I get close to another object in the scene. The laws of rigidbody are ignored and passes through other objects it normally would bump against.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you're forcing its position to be at a specific spot relative to the object it's "stuck" to: it is no longer a rigid body being controlled by the physics engine. The object it's stuck to *has no idea that it can't move forward any more, does so, and causes interpenetration.*

You need to add this object's collision volume to the controlling object's hierarchy so that the physics engine *does* know about it.

Comment: A good practice concerning Unity physic objects is to know if you are going to manage them by forcing their positions or using the physics engine. Whatever you choose (and I always tend to use the engine), stuck to it.

Comment: Very good point, @Greg . Personally I prefer not using the physics engine (I've never had much luck making entities move around in a believable fashion using `AddForce()`, everything acts like it's on ice: low acceleration, wide corners, and no maximum speed).

Answer (score 0):

i had a conversation amongst some friends as well, and what you indicate is right, it is ignoring the physics engine.

someone indicating using a  which works fabulously.

```
        gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        gameObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = collision.rigidbody;
```